# Sed insert file contents rather than file name

Tags: bash, sed, replace

I have two files and would like to insert the contents of one file into the other, replacing a specified line.

File 1:

```
abc
def
ghi
jkl
```

File 2:

```
123
```

**The following code is what I have.**

```
file1=numbers.txt
file2=letters.txt
linenumber=3s
echo $file1
echo $file2
sed "$linenumber/.*/r $file1/" $file2
```

**Which results in the output:**

```
abc
def
r numbers.txt
jkl
```

**The output I am hoping for is:**

```
abc
def
123
jkl
```

I thought it could be an issue with bash variables but I still get the same output when I manually enter the information.

How am I misunderstanding sed and/or the read command?

Comment: why `s` in linenumber?

Comment: @KamilCuk if I am understanding sed correctly doesn't "s" represent substitution? I am attempting to substitute/replace line #3 with the contents of file 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script replaces the line with the string `"r $file1"`. The part in `sed` in `s` command is not re-interpreted as a command, but taken literally.

You can:

```
linenumber=3
sed "$linenumber"' { 
        r '"$file1"'
        d
}' "$file2"
```

Read line number 3, print file1 and then delete the line.

See [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-37) for a good explanation and reference.

Surely we can make that a oneliner:

```
sed -e "$linenumber"' { r '"$file2"$'\n''d; }' "$file1"
```

Life example at [tutorialpoints](http://tpcg.io/Cgfr4H).

Comment: Thank you but when I run the code it just results in
`abc
def
ghi
jkl`

Comment: Och I think i mixed file1 with file2, try to swap them

Comment: When I swap them it changes to
`123
123
123
123`

Comment: It works perfectly on tutorial points but still isn't working on my terminal. I am running Ubuntu 18.04 and have reinstalled sed but to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: : / I can guess: encoding. Try running `dos2unix` on files. Maybe post the output of `cat file | hexdump -C` of those files? usually sed has hard time handling DOS newlines.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `c` command as follows:

```
linenumber=3
sed "${linenumber}c $(< $file1)" "$file2"
```

This replaces the current line with the text that comes after `c`.

---

Your command didn't work because it expands to this:

```
sed "3s/.*/r numbers.txt/" letters.txt
```

and you can't use `r` like that. `r` has to be the command that is being run.

Comment: Thank you for your help but I receive 
`123
123
123
123`

Comment: Ah, you have `linenumber` still set to `3s`, probably. I've added how I set it.